# Can i Install new emoticons on Ubuntu as in Kubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, kde

Is it possible? or it's just a KDE specific feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to specifically is a KDE specific feature, so no, you cannot do the same on Ubuntu.

Pidgin and emesene support emoticon themes, so maybe you can give one of these two a try.

Comment: yeah, i was hoping i could do the same  :(